# Java add column in a query with where and concact

Tags: java, mysql, where-clause

How add a column in a query with where and concact? I try to use a Arraylist but is not correct

```
String search = searchField.getText();
    ArrayList<String> check = new ArrayList<>();
    if (CheckBoxCodice.isSelected()){
        check.add("Codice");
    }
    if (CheckBoxRagioneSociale.isSelected()){
        check.add("Ragione_Sociale");
    }
    if (CheckBoxComune.isSelected()){
        check.add("comune");
    }

    UpdateTabella("select * from anagraficaclifor where concact (" + check +") like '%"+ search + "%'");
```

Comment: Could you please post the actual Query you want to build ? Based on that I can give the answer I am not sure  "select * from Table where Column(VALUE) like %SOME%" is the right syntax

Comment: The number of variables in the where change in order how many check boxes are selected

Comment: You could probably the check the answer I have provided below  . ArrayList is converted into  String1,String2 format  and adding quotes may not be required

Answer (score 1):

Try use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
builder.append(  "yourstring" );
builder.append(",");
builder.append(  "yourstring2" );
```

and if builder is ready you can use

```
builder.toString()
```

which gives you

```
"yourstring,yourstring2"
```

EDIT:
You can just add

```
builder.append(",");
builder.append(  "yourstring2" );
```

in each if statement and use in the end

```
builder.deleteCharAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the probem is how many chekboxes are selected and when in the string builder add the coma or not

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35927627/edit) the question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you think your query is syntactically correct then you should add \' for contact. 
and you should remove  [] from the arrays to String.

```
UpdateTabella("select * from anagraficaclifor where concact (" + check.toString().substring(1).replaceFirst("]", "") +") like '%"+ search + "%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I get the problem now... You should make your SQL statement with the `StringBuilder` and make a union

```
SELECT field_1[, field_2,…]
FROM table_1[, table_2,…]
UNION [ALL]
SELECT field_a[, field_b,...]
FROM table_a[, table_b,…];
```

I will see if I can figure out a way...

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
for(int i = 0; i < check.size(); i++) {
    builder.append("SELECT * FROM ... ");
    if(i != check.size()) {
        builder.append(" UNION [ALL] ");
    } else if(i == check.size()) {
        builder.append(";");
}
```

Something like this might work.